# How to Disable the Checkout access to the users in svn

Tags: svn, svn-administraton

How can i enable the checkout option for the administrator and not for the users. my need is the users only have the right of importing the files but they should not have the right of checking out the files from the repository. am very thankful to you if u people help me in this task.

thanks in advance,

prasad

Comment: Why do you need users to be able to change a repository but not see what they changed? That sounds like an XY problem to me. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: hi  Actually i need to create a exam portal by using svn tool where the users(students) cannot have the access checking out the files they should have only the right of checking in because if the checkout the files there may be chance of copying the files. and one more doubt is can we keep someone(user) as the administrator in this svn tool..

Comment: And why do you think SVN is the best back-end for this tool? Surely there are ready-made dropbox tools available. Have you not been able to find one to meet your needs?

Comment: may be there are many more tools but i want to create that task by using the SVN tool. so iam searching for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you *insist* on using SVN for your exam turn-in, then I guess I would suggest:

1. Create a folder for each student. Maybe even per student, per assignment.
2. Give each student full access (read-write) but ONLY to their own folder.
3. If needed, install a pre-commit server-side hook to disallow any modifications, only allowing "add" operations.

But I still think SVN is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have Write permissions (importing to repo is writing) without Read permissions. Three possible types of access for repository are only `NONE|READ|READWRITE`